# Custom user table containing specific role

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a Wordpress plugin which allows users to sign up. Users are given a role called "employee". I want to create a page inside the plugin which shows the usual user table, but only show the users with role "employee".
Basically the page should be like: /wp-admin/users.php?role=employee

However the rabithole of wordpress tables is deep, and i have a strong feeling that im making this more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Code examples? things you have tried that don't seem to work?

Comment: thanks @MarkTruitt i have tried to rebuild the whole thing from scratch using several tutorials. but  i wondered if there was an easier way, since i want it to function just like the /wp-admin/users.php?role=employee url

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use this post written by the WPMU team as a reference:
[Adding WordPress Admin Tables to Plugins with WP_List_Table](https://wpmudev.com/blog/wordpress-admin-tables/)

But, in my opinion, this method comes with a lot of boilerplate code. If the creation of a WordPress-like table is not a mandatory requirement for what you're building, I'd rather recommend you to build a table using some custom PHP and HTML/CSS.

Comment: I actually tried rebuilding it, but was suprised by the amount of work needed, if figured their might be a better solution apart from starting from scratch and rebuilding the whole thing.

i basically want the /users.php table but query only the users with role: "Employee"

Comment: In this case, all you need to do is to add a new admin page using add_menu_page() function, and then use WP_User_Query or get_users() in its callback function

Comment: alright i added a menupage which calls the function jqml_users. that function looks like this:

'function jqml_users(){
  $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'employee ) );
  print_r(get_users($user_query));
}'

Now ofcourse it just prints out the users, because thats what this function does. Now i just need to figure out a way to display the data in the users table. Do you have any clue on how to do that?